# Get percentage based on value in previous row

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

For the given data:

```
+---+--------+------+
|CID| number | rum  |
+---+--------+------+
| 1 | 1.0000 | NULL |
| 3 | 2.0000 | NULL |
| 5 | 2.0000 | NULL |
| 6 | 4.0000 | NULL |
+---+--------+------+
```

I want to calculate rum with percentage change of current and previous number.

```
rum = (currNumber - prevNumber) / prevNumber * 100
```

Expected result:

```
+---+--------+------+
|CID| number | rum  |
+---+--------+------+
| 1 | 1.0000 | NULL |
| 3 | 2.0000 |100.0 |
| 5 | 2.0000 |  0.0 |
| 6 | 4.0000 |100.0 |
+---+--------+------+
```

`LAG` function doesn't work here in MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the rows are ordered based on CID you can find previous row using correlated subquery:

```
SELECT CID, number, (
    SELECT (c.number - p.number) / p.number * 100
    FROM t AS p
    WHERE p.CID < c.CID
    ORDER BY p.CID DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS rum
FROM t AS c
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/983fc06/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate `lag()` with a variable:

```
set @num = null;

select 
    cid,
    number,
    (number- lag_number)/lag_number * 100 rum
from (
    select 
        cid, 
        @num lag_number, 
        @num := number number 
    from mytable 
    order by cid
) t
order by cid
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8fa9bd55dc92dd6db8a22271d55b1a5d)**:

```
cid | number |  rum
--: | -----: | ---:
  1 | 1.0000 | null
  3 | 2.0000 |  100
  5 | 2.0000 |    0
  6 | 4.0000 |  100
```

Comment: Using variables for this is a bad idea.

Comment: There is an `order by` in a sub query. That is nonsense but MySQL allows you to do that but it may or may not honor the inner order by. There is no guarantee.

Comment: @SalmanA: to my knowledge, the order by clause in the subquery is what guarantees that the variable will be correctly assigned the previous value. But I have to agree that your solution is smarter here anyway, hence +1.

Comment: @gmb https://mysqlserverteam.com/row-numbering-ranking-how-to-use-less-user-variables-in-mysql-queries/... search for "joining people with country".