# Update Value based on previous row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

This question is based on my previous question given below.
[Get percentage based on value in previous row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833363/get-percentage-based-on-value-in-previous-row)

Instead of getting a select statement, 
I want an **update** statement to fill the rum column using update query.

Input:

```
+---+--------+------+
|CID| number | rum  |
+---+--------+------+
| 1 | 1.0000 | NULL |
| 3 | 2.0000 | NULL |
| 5 | 2.0000 | NULL |
| 6 | 4.0000 | NULL |
+---+--------+------+
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+------+
|CID| number | rum  |
+---+--------+------+
| 1 | 1.0000 | NULL |
| 3 | 2.0000 |100.0 |
| 5 | 2.0000 |  0.0 |
| 6 | 4.0000 |100.0 |
+---+--------+------+
```

Formula:

```
rum = (currNumber - prevNumber) / prevNumber * 100
```

Comment: [Simulate lag function in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49699931/5070879) - native support for LAG function starting from MySQL 8.0

Comment: Lag function doesn't work in MySQL. I need an update query. I do not have mastery on sql other than joins and group bys

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: thanks the lag function worked it didn't work on my previous mariadb but now it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN` and window functions in an `UPDATE`.  One method is:

```
update t join
       (select t.*, lag(number) over (order by cid) as prev_number
        from t
       ) tt
       on tt.cid = t.cid
    set rum = (number - prev_number) * 100 / prev_number;
```