# How to speed up loop in MySQL, fill lines based on previous row value

Tags: mysql, loops, procedure

My database is composed by individual job contracts. I am updating some information to enhance the quality of the data. More precisely, I am updating information regarding workers' residence codes. In the following image I am showing an example of my database in the following image (the .csv version could be found [here](https://github.com/nicolacaravaggio/example_data/blob/151180af63262c810908eb8b1f38027321b97948/data_example_7252022.csv)).

[image]

While variables are explained here below.

```
id -----------> "Primary key" [indexed]
worker_id ----> "Id associated ot each individual/worker" [indexed]
dt_start -----> "Starting date of the job contract"
dt_end -------> "End date of the job contract"
cod_res ------> "Old residence code"
cod_res_rev --> "New residence code"
id_lag -------> "Previous id, if the 'worker_id' is the same" [indexed]
id_lead ------> "Subsequent id, it the 'worker_id' is the same" [indexed]
```

As you can notice, the column `cod_res_rev` is characterized is full of `NULL` values. This is because the reconstruction of the variable `cod_res_rev` with the updated residence values it was based solely on specific contracts (those for which the worker had had an actual change of residence - but this is redundant for the purposes of my question). Therefore, my goal is to fill each `NULL` value of the column `cod_res_rev` with the previous one, if not missing, until the next non-empty value is reached and continue like this for each worker. The result should be something like this.

[image]

I attempted to achieve my goal through the following procedure.

```
-- The loop is performed based on the maximum number of entries per worker in the database identified through the table 'max_count'.
drop table if exists max_count;
create table max_count 
as select worker_id, count(*) n 
from ml_arm
group by worker_id;
alter table max_count add unique index (worker_id); 

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS doiterate;
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE doiterate()
BEGIN
  DECLARE total INT unsigned DEFAULT 0;
  WHILE total <= (select MAX(n) from max_count) DO

update ml_arm a
left outer join ml_arm b on a.id_lag = b.id
set a.cod_res_rev = 
    case 
    when a.cod_res_rev is NULL and a.worker_id = b.worker_id and b.cod_res_rev is not NULL
    then b.cod_res_rev 
    else a.cod_res_rev 
    end;

    SET total = total + 1;
  END WHILE;
END//  

delimiter ;

CALL doiterate();
```

However, I do not believe this is the optimal way to update my table. In fact, by database if composed by about 25 million of rows and the value from `select MAX(n) from max_count` is about 4,000. I kindly ask you for any suggestion on faster approaches to update my table. I am using MySQL 8.0.22. Thank you in advance.

Eventually, here below there is a command to create a sample table of my database with a bunch of entries.

```
drop table if exists ml_arm;
create table ml_arm (
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    worker_id int,
    dt_start date,
    dt_end date,
    cod_res varchar(50),
    cod_res_rev varchar(50),
    id_lag int,
    id_lead int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into 
    ml_arm(id, worker_id, dt_start, dt_end, cod_res, cod_res_rev, id_lag, id_lead)
values
    ('12', '20', '2014-05-02', '2014-07-08', '', 'I040', NULL, '13'),
    ('13', '20', '2017-01-14', '2017-01-31', '', NULL, '12', '14'),
    ('14', '20', '2017-11-06', '2017-12-15', 'I040', NULL, '13', NULL),
    ('20', '29', '2014-11-24', '2017-02-11', '', 'N.D.', NULL, NULL),
    ('21', '42', '2016-01-22', '2016-05-05', 'G582', 'G582', NULL, NULL),
    ('23', '45', '2013-08-07', '2014-04-06', 'G582', 'G582', NULL, '24'),
    ('24', '45', '2014-05-07', '2014-05-10', 'G582', NULL, '23', NULL),
    ('25', '48', '2012-08-11', '2012-08-31', 'G582', 'G582', NULL, '26'),
    ('26', '48', '2013-08-10', '2013-08-31', 'G582', NULL, '25', NULL),
    ('53', '71', '2016-12-01', '2017-05-31', '', 'N.D.', NULL, '54'),
    ('54', '71', '2017-06-01', '2020-05-29', '', NULL, '53', '55'),
    ('55', '71', '2020-06-01', '2099-01-01', '', NULL, '54', NULL)
    ;
```

Comment: Do not use procedure, use single query.

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (2 users, 5-7 rows each, is enough). Specify your MySQL version.

Comment: UDV usage (inline assignment) is deprecated. If you have 8+ version I'd recommend you to use lateral subquery instead.

Comment: Thank you Akina. I am using MySQL 8.0.22. Furtheremore, at the end of my question I have added a sample data with CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO.

Comment: We can ignore the column `code_res` for this discussion?

Comment: Since you are using 8.0, have you experimented with `lag` and `LEAD(1) OVER ... PARTITION BY ...`?  That would get rid of the id_lead/lag columns.  But is it fast enough?

Comment: @RickJames, the column `code_res` is actually useless, I just needed to check differences but for the update/loop is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

By following Gordon Linoff's answer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489087/update-value-based-on-previous-row-in-mysql) it seems to work:

```
UPDATE ml_arm t1
  JOIN (
    SELECT id, @s:=IF(cod_res_rev IS NULL, @s, cod_res_rev) cod_res_rev
      FROM (SELECT * FROM ml_arm ORDER BY id) r,
    (SELECT @s:= NULL) t
  ) t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.cod_res_rev = t2.cod_res_rev;
```